# Connect to ejabberd server using a certificate

Tags: certificate, ejabberd

I want to connect to my ejabberd server from another machine using a certificate instead of a login/password. I've looked for authentication client-to-server with a certificate for ejabberd, but i couldn't find something helpfull.
If anyone has any ideas how it cas be done, I'm taking..

Answer (score 0):

As of version 16.02, ejabberd Community Server does not yet support client cert authentication.

However, if your questions is about communication encryption, you can indeed configure ejabberd with Starttls support to use TLS between client and server. A service like Let's encrypt can provide such certificates for free: https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, in this case, what is the use of the certificate that comes with ejabberd ?

Comment: ejabberd certificate is an example self-signed certificate that is presented by the server to prove that he is who it pretend to be (as such you should replace it with a true certificate delivered by a trusted certificate authority). It has nothing to do with client authentication.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact, I want to authenticate some devices to my server. In this case, as you have said, you can not do this simply by using a certificate. Do you have any ideas how can I authenticate these devices and at the same time maximazing security ?

Comment: You can generate a trusted certificate and connect with login and password under and encrypted connection. Most clients / library support this. The Let's encrypt service for example can provide you with free server certificate: https://letsencrypt.org/